# Tornado app throwing exception even though app seems to work with FB login api

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7, tornado

I am working on a simple tornado app in which I am using FB authentication for user login and I need email id of that user associated with the user.

Following is my handler of FB login, first it gets access token and using that access token again it makes call to FB for email.

```
class FAuthLoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
      @tornado.web.asynchronous
      def get(self):
          user_id = self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')

          if self.get_argument('code', None):
              self.get_authenticated_user(
                  redirect_uri=settings.redirect_url,
                  client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'],
                  client_secret=self.settings['facebook_secret'],
                  code=self.get_argument('code'),
                  callback=self.async_callback(self._on_facebook_login))
              return
          elif self.get_secure_cookie('access_token'):
              self.redirect('/')

          self.authorize_redirect(
              redirect_uri=settings.redirect_url,
              client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'],
              extra_params={'scope': 'email'}
          )


      def _on_facebook_login(self, user):
          def _save_user_profile(user):
              if not user:
                  raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Facebook authentication failed.")
              # print user
              # print user.get('email')

          if not user:
              self.clear_all_cookies()
              raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, 'Facebook authentication failed')

          # does user['id'] already exists in DB? if not, add request for 
          # email from FB, insert both id and email

          self.facebook_request("/me", access_token=user["access_token"], callback=_save_user_profile)
          self.set_secure_cookie('trakr', str(user['id']))
          self.set_secure_cookie('access_token', str(user['access_token']))
          self.redirect('/')
```

Following is my complete error log:

```
[I 140128 20:52:09 autoreload:191] main.py modified; restarting server
[I 140128 20:52:15 web:1728] 304 GET / (::1) 0.58ms
[I 140128 20:52:23 web:1728] 302 GET /auth/flogin (::1) 0.99ms
[E 140128 20:52:23 web:1305] Uncaught exception GET /auth/flogin (::1)
    HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8757', method='GET', uri='/auth/flogin', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Host': 'localhost:8757', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': 'access_token=Q0FBVHBjWUFHbFFVQkFGWkNQU0J5eDVFTWcwR2wyeFNNeXZHQlpCYUVxZkNzMGRSSzJjNEN6MHFDa0lWZnhmdzlFREp6SmlxOE1kN0loVm1zQVZ3d1RiT3pvSko1MFRsczYxdlVkaU1VS3Y2VHFFTXN3WEFpNzh0eTRtckxMaHgyNjVGejRKbGRkOGFVd3JWZjQ3WkJ6ZDk4ZEhRMWxVWkE0VVpBMVZnUThndjBNY00zSHJxWkNR|1390922478|305e1721c5138255a222432c83c2a4d6d330cb8d; trakr=NjE5MzU1ODA0|1390922478|7681ab19f6e2c43879c77a139c3de9d9daca493a; user_name="QXZpbmFzaCBTYWpqYW5zaGV0dHk=|1390922478|46211cd889f4037eef1c46e1767f185d0ca2656e"', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1192, in _stack_context_handle_exception
        raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1375, in wrapper
        result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "main.py", line 73, in get
        extra_params={'scope': 'email'}#'user_photos, publish_stream'}
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 234, in wrapper
        raise_exc_info(exc_info)
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 222, in wrapper
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/auth.py", line 576, in authorize_redirect
        url_concat(self._OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL, args))
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 578, in redirect
        raise Exception("Cannot redirect after headers have been written")
    Exception: Cannot redirect after headers have been written
[I 140128 20:52:23 web:1728] 304 GET / (::1) 0.49ms
[I 140128 20:52:59 web:1728] 304 GET /auth/logout (::1) 1.45ms
[I 140128 20:53:02 web:1728] 302 GET /auth/flogin (::1) 0.65ms
[I 140128 20:53:02 web:1728] 302 GET /auth/flogin (::1) 0.61ms
[W 140128 20:53:04 auth:85] Facebook auth error: HTTPResponse(_body=None,buffer=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x10ed6e7d0>,code=400,effective_url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_secret=71f12beedbeca0c8b7f0b8f799a0b24d&code=AQCT93GoGYzZisnts1MkTWzpGGfdPu2nKgi5GIX0_vr2A6jtck0jdouPEFYUEEm_w086K-4XpHedcqZJ9djTCprH6xiMwnL39iLF5Mf3yM_1eJDJJgPzz6M7Pm9XauUmGZa2PJlEY37y6RKmri_IEi0FMev3tpTuhUdcDrkqZ2aMgECqKFGIU6xj5xWHvyipNtlJ_iK1rU-Ul90itjT7b9Mii5TXAflYZFqSya7QfEOrZZjylydX_akBrXZAxOzxmNDc6sIMpeC1FMO5G5lTMmcR3doaa9ex59IT1u7AhXk3C0qnF81YC_3fOO2GoWk7GPY&client_id=1382573595333893&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8757%2Fauth%2Fflogin',error=HTTPError('HTTP 400: Bad Request',),headers={'Content-Length': '97', 'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'X-Fb-Debug': 'wqhG+tPsSx+eZZVWzBEwJz0LuKc70mSstadFOx2TKN0=', 'X-Fb-Rev': '1097933', 'Connection': 'close', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store', 'Date': 'Tue, 28 Jan 2014 15:23:04 GMT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8', 'Www-Authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" "This authorization code has been used."'},reason='Bad Request',request=<tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest object at 0x10e6bbd50>,request_time=1.221066951751709,time_info={})
[W 140128 20:53:04 web:1302] 500 GET /auth/flogin?code=AQCT93GoGYzZisnts1MkTWzpGGfdPu2nKgi5GIX0_vr2A6jtck0jdouPEFYUEEm_w086K-4XpHedcqZJ9djTCprH6xiMwnL39iLF5Mf3yM_1eJDJJgPzz6M7Pm9XauUmGZa2PJlEY37y6RKmri_IEi0FMev3tpTuhUdcDrkqZ2aMgECqKFGIU6xj5xWHvyipNtlJ_iK1rU-Ul90itjT7b9Mii5TXAflYZFqSya7QfEOrZZjylydX_akBrXZAxOzxmNDc6sIMpeC1FMO5G5lTMmcR3doaa9ex59IT1u7AhXk3C0qnF81YC_3fOO2GoWk7GPY (::1): Facebook authentication failed
[E 140128 20:53:04 web:1728] 500 GET /auth/flogin?code=AQCT93GoGYzZisnts1MkTWzpGGfdPu2nKgi5GIX0_vr2A6jtck0jdouPEFYUEEm_w086K-4XpHedcqZJ9djTCprH6xiMwnL39iLF5Mf3yM_1eJDJJgPzz6M7Pm9XauUmGZa2PJlEY37y6RKmri_IEi0FMev3tpTuhUdcDrkqZ2aMgECqKFGIU6xj5xWHvyipNtlJ_iK1rU-Ul90itjT7b9Mii5TXAflYZFqSya7QfEOrZZjylydX_akBrXZAxOzxmNDc6sIMpeC1FMO5G5lTMmcR3doaa9ex59IT1u7AhXk3C0qnF81YC_3fOO2GoWk7GPY (::1) 1223.15ms
[I 140128 20:53:05 web:1728] 302 GET /auth/flogin?code=AQDHHt-ajYsUK5lkqVtreZuL9d5p9xx5dgzpUejdRoQNszwTPxJe91cs4XtX70WQeaegdmuczaAuOQXhi6yraN8hnI_aHjWLDdKfXBgtwDllsnslXP5XdiUpstRXkC2KgiQEU_ZYb9YlQU0UvYKZZ6sQWt8_y58fK05Aln-i5pHSGG6NHUipk_beeSZEgR-hTIWfH-MSwE4EUL3AvRlmmo_egrpknmSD2KT5_4trkz_pWkBJRHFoZech-Qspyz5SGIjvyiUFxiHfcZ4iWWtSYSpF86JOrKH0tyxMGKDrDDq2JBhLqjIBkANFEX0V1lGj0ss (::1) 2457.34ms
{u'username': u'av...y', u'bio': u'I am uninteresting !', u'first_name': u'Av...h', u'last_name': u'S...y', u'verified': True, u'name': u'Av...y', u'locale': u'en_US', u'gender': u'male', u'email': u'avi...@gmail.com', u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/avi...y', u'timezone': 5.5, u'updated_time': u'2013-10-08T08:40:52+0000', u'id': u'6...4'}
avi...n@gmail.com
```

The first error is 'Exception: Cannot redirect after headers have been written', why is such error?

and secondly, looking at the log it is still able to fetch my email and print it, but it throws Facebook auth error. It says in header 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" "This authorization code has been used."'},reason='Bad Request', even though it was able to fetch and display email. So what's wrong?

**EDIT**: I just logged out, cleared all cookies and re-logged and now I don't see any FB login error. I think it was mostly using old access key? Not sure.

Once I am logged in, if I send a get request to login again, I am getting the "Cannot redirect after headers have been written" error. Why is such error? Note it is displayed on the console, on browser there is no error. i.e. user will never see this error. Here is the full log:

```
[I 140128 23:33:14 web:1728] 304 GET /auth/logout (::1) 1.57ms
[I 140128 23:33:17 web:1728] 302 GET /auth/flogin (::1) 0.60ms
[I 140128 23:33:17 web:1728] 302 GET /auth/flogin (::1) 0.59ms
[I 140128 23:33:20 web:1728] 302 GET /auth/flogin?code=AQDIQxT3YoQmQlyzivz4FjSotn1SVVyQeJNNknu3P18--b9Gkq9n0ZFKDhLHD31M-MVD6O2CJACHl6TxMyRKweeL834BYzNyCXqe40QmZYhFPm_eluKWkqhxbEvl0c9bx0VOa5YMLAr1448M9hx2Re11NWALjDDwkeF-KKwZXbE26iYbTCAxKdRdk34CJaj1RqQQs3vGPBUAmpzvNHdXgWRpuELRsJftgijTWA1dw1pEN1KeE4MOgdvw6L73Yfo3v-OJI0AavHJh0TXBsp0z4to5R1Qr2h97oTEBH1RvGY559NnmJuiW7z0tSAiTGnL5lgo (::1) 2486.21ms
[I 140128 23:33:20 web:1728] 304 GET / (::1) 0.46ms
{u'username': u'av...y', u'bio': u'I am uninteresting !', u'first_name': u'Av...h', u'last_name': u'S...y', u'verified': True, u'name': u'Av...y', u'locale': u'en_US', u'gender': u'male', u'email': u'avi...@gmail.com', u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/avi...y', u'timezone': 5.5, u'updated_time': u'2013-10-08T08:40:52+0000', u'id': u'6...4'}
avi...@gmail.com
[I 140128 23:33:26 web:1728] 302 GET /auth/flogin (::1) 0.92ms
[E 140128 23:33:26 web:1305] Uncaught exception GET /auth/flogin (::1)
    HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8757', method='GET', uri='/auth/flogin', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', headers={'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Cookie': 'access_token="Q0FBVHBjWUFHbFFVQkFQQzNwdTh1aUJFdnZDb3NrRWpqN2pJQ0F5VFZrNW1aQWllWWFPaENiaERaQXMyRThaQzQ4c0V4UW1FN2F5YzVrcEZYcVJzSndxYnJzM3RxQU9hM2gyNlVlRWlvanNaQmFGbW1uY3VXcDF2NmNEaUVpNEJaQlEzdDhGc3pWTUVGNVFqR0Z4TGRzZ0ZIb1F1WkNVYkszdWRKNE12SnE0MWNXNFpCOEphNVJzMw==|1390932200|6dfe36f5d6f3909915fe3d3af8088a983dbb67be"; trakr=NjE5MzU1ODA0|1390932200|9298aab581e8db81e65334307f04ebfcd98f6e90; user_name="QXZpbmFzaCBTYWpqYW5zaGV0dHk=|1390932200|95fb3b517a773e7c98c8ef9cef9b627afcf79141"', 'Host': 'localhost:8757', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1192, in _stack_context_handle_exception
        raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1375, in wrapper
        result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "main.py", line 73, in get
        extra_params={'scope': 'email'}#'user_photos, publish_stream'}
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 234, in wrapper
        raise_exc_info(exc_info)
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 222, in wrapper
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/auth.py", line 576, in authorize_redirect
        url_concat(self._OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL, args))
      File "/Users/avi/Documents/code/trakr/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 578, in redirect
        raise Exception("Cannot redirect after headers have been written")
    Exception: Cannot redirect after headers have been written
[I 140128 23:33:26 web:1728] 304 GET / (::1) 0.47ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return after the `self.redirect` in the first `elif` block; the error is because you're trying to redirect twice in the same request (when it falls through to `authorize_redirect` below).

Comment: I have made changes to OP, but I think you are answering about the first error of 'Cannot redirect...'. May I know why `self.redirect` has to return? Also I am not able to understand how I am redirecting the request twice.

Comment: If the `code` argument is not present but the `access_token` cookie is, then you will call `self.redirect` and then fall through to `authorize_redirect`.  You only want to do one of the two redirects.  Either return after `self.redirect` or put the `authorize_redirect` call in an `else` block so you don't try to do two things at once.

Comment: I don't see the error now. I added a `return` statement after `self.redirect` in elif block. I want to understand one thing, why add `return` statement after `self.redirect`? I thought `self.redirect` will transfer the control to outside & after that line no code being executed. Also if I change from `elif` to `else`, I am still getting the same 'Cannot redirect after headers have been written' error.